# Kendo UI Grid Persist state in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have some problems loading the saved state of the grid in Angular.

This is the grids HTML:

```
<div id="grid" kendo-grid k-options="GridOptions" k-ng-delay="GridOptions"></div>
```

Later I start my Http call and the $scope.GridOptions are filled in and the grid works fine.

Then I save the state of my grid this way:

```
$scope.GridOptionsBackup = kendo.stringify($scope.GridOptions);
```

This works fine and when i print the output in the console. It looks like this:

> {"dataSource":{"schema":{"data":"Data"},"transport":{},"serverSorting":true,"table":null,"fields":[{"encoded":true,"field":"WidgetName","title":"Name","template":"#: data.WidgetName#"},{"encoded":true,"field":"WidgetDescription","title":"Description","template":"#: data.WidgetDescription#"}]},"columns":[{"field":"WidgetName","title":"Name","template":"#: data.WidgetName#"},{"field":"WidgetDescription","title":"Description","template":"#: data.WidgetDescription#"}],"sortable":{"mode":"multiple","allowUnsort":true},"scrollable":true}

When i try to reload the grid with the saved state, i read the JSON, parse it and reassign it to $scope.GridOptions. But this don't work:

```
$scope.GridOptions = JSON.parse($scope.GridOptionsBackup);
```

Why is the grid not updated after this line of code?

I really appreciate any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

I had to give the kendo-grid a name:

```
<div kendo-grid="GridBram" k-options="GridOptions" k-ng-delay="GridOptions"></div>
```

In my Angular code, the name is automatically binded to a scope. There i can use the same (strange) get and setOptions methods that are used in jQuery. I also used a var to store the JSON.

This is my code:

```
var savedState = null;

$scope.saveO = function () {
    savedState = kendo.stringify($scope.GridBram.getOptions());
    console.log(test);
}

$scope.loadO = function () {
    $scope.GridBram.setOptions(JSON.parse(savedState));
}
```

Like this, u can save and load the state of your grid in Angular!

Comment: it doesn't work for me, when I try to use it on $scope I get undefined - can you show more of your code? how did you initialize the grid? with jQuery or with Angular?

Comment: I initialise the grid with Angular. Can you maybe give a link to a plunker with your code so i can help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856910/kendo-ui-and-angular-no-widget-in-scope here is my question so you can see a snippet of code

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 angular buttons 
  lt button kendo-button ng-click="save()" gt
            Save State A
       lt /button gt
       lt button kendo-button ng-click="load()" gt
            Load State A
       lt /button gt
 var savedState = null;

```
    $scope.save = function () {
       // alert('sav')
        savedState = kendo.stringify($scope.GridMAS.getOptions());

    }

    $scope.load = function () {
        //alert('lod')
        $scope.GridMAS.setOptions(JSON.parse(savedState));
    }
```

Worked for me