# Kendo UI and angular - no widget in $scope

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo UI version 2014.2.716 with AngularJS version 1.2.27, and I made a grid using a directive

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
    <div id="myGrid" kendo-grid k-options="{some options}"></div>
    <button ng-click="ctrl.doSomething()"></div>
</div>
```

I read that if you give a name to the grid (like this: kendo-grid="myGridOnScope"), you can access the widget in the controller scope in this way:

```
myModule.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
   this.doSomething = function() {
       console.log($scope.myGridOnScope);
   }
}
```

The console.log should log a widget object, but in my case it's undefined. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help

Comment: you need to modify the code as  <div kendo-grid="myGrid".... ></div>

Comment: if you read carefully you'd see that I said i tried that.. but anyway the question is answered already

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found out the problem myself, so I'm going to post an answer if someone has the same problem. If you use the controllerAs syntax in AngularJS, you can't just write the name of the widget - **you have to prefix it with your controller alias.**

Take a look at this example:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
    <div kendo-grid="myGridName"></div>
</div>
```

This will not give you the grid object on the `$scope` - for that you need to add the `ctrl` prefix:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
    <div kendo-grid="ctrl.myGridName"></div>
</div>
```

Now you have access to the widget in your controller like this:

```
angular.module('MyModule',['kendo.directives'])
    .controller('MyController', function($scope){
        // this gives you the widget object
        console.log(this.myGridName);

        // however, this doesn't work
        console.log($scope.myGridName);
});
```

I hope I helped someone with this post.
Cheers,

Comment: You are a hero! I spent quite some time building a work around! Now I have `$scope.grid = this.grid` at the beginning of my controller and problem solved :) Note `kendo-grid=myGridName` works for me (without adding the controller)

Comment: no wonder only one grid did not work properly on the page. hours man, HOURSSS. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try waiting for the event that Kendo emits.

*Html*

`<div kendo-grid="grid" options="gridOptions"></div>`

*Javascript*

```
$scope.$on("kendoWidgetCreated", function(event, widget){
    if (widget === $scope.grid) {
        console.log($scope.grid);
    }
});
```

**Edit:** [See this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yIakSAZe4UoIJ70gBu6l?p=preview)

Comment: It doesn't log any widgets. If I try it without the if condition it logs my grid but there is still nothing on $scope.

Answer (score 0):

It is because angular is too fast and the kendo element doesn't exist when you try to set the options.

I solved this with a watch.

This is my html code:

```
<div kendo-grid="ListDesign"></div>
```

And this is my angular code

```
 $scope.$watch('ListDesign', function () {
        if ($scope.ListDesign != undefined) {
            var gridOptions = {
                columns: columns,
                sortable: {
                    mode: 'multiple',
                    allowUnsort: true
                }
            };
            $scope.ListDesign.setOptions(gridOptions);
            $scope.ListDesign.setDataSource(dataSource);
        }
    });
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work, I tried $watching for the widget but it's always undefined... I'm concerned it has to do something with the version of Angular - which versions of Kendo and Angular do you use?

Comment: Yesterday i updated my Kendo version and it still works the way I explained. Now i'm using `Kendo UI v2014.3.1316` and `AngularJS v1.3.5`. First i include my `jQuery v.2.1.3`, then my angular, and then the kendo.all.min.js file...